# MongoDB on Vagrant via Port Forwarding issue

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, getaddrinfo

I've recently installed mongodb on my CentOS 6 VM running on Vagrant.

I added port forwarding to Vagrantfile to forward the mongo port

```
config.vm.forward_port 27017, 127017
```

I configured mongod to start automatically when the server starts and have confirmed that the service starts as intended.

however when i run `mongo localhost:127017` from my host machine (not vagrant) i get the following error

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.2
connecting to: localhost:127017/test
Fri Jan 20 13:58:28 getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Fri Jan 20 13:58:28 Error shell/mongo.js:81
exception: connect failed
```

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce using centos 6.2 w/ mongodb 2.0.2. What kind of box are you running and where did you get it from?

Comment: This issue comes from trying to query the mongo server on vagrant (centos 6) from the host machine (MacOSX)

Comment: do you have any other ports forwarded that are working (80, 22)?  Also, port forwarding requires a virtual machine restart, or VirtualBox won't pick up the ports.

Comment: Does telnetting into that port form OSX work for you? I think it could be a firewall issue, and unless you setup the virtualbox box yourself I wouldn't trust it. Could have all sorts of issues.

Comment: Adam C - Yes, port 80 successfully forwards to 8080 and i have rebooted the vm several times.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to try connecting to that port (27017) locally from within the VM - essentially that will prove that mongod is running and listening (also "lsof -i | grep mongod") - once that is done you have essentially proved it some sort of forwarding/firewall issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TCP port numbers are 16-bit unsigned, which mean the max value is 65535 (2^16), and you're trying with 127017.

Answer (score 19):

You will need to set the mongod bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 (which is the loopback address) so that all interfaces can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the mongo server from vagrant ssh? If not, you might want to make sure that mongod is running.

Do you have an `ip_bind` set up in your mongodb.conf or mongod startup script? (If you do, you might want to unset it--not exactly sure how vagrant's port forwarding works, but this might be what's causing the problem.)

Comment: yes, I am able to do a mongo query from vagrant ssh. This issue comes from trying to query the mongo server from the host machine (MacOSX)

Answer (score -3):

`bind_ip to 0.0.0.0` does not work. Try `bind_ip=127.0.0.1,10.0.0.25`, that worked for me.