# MongoDB connect error

Tags: mongodb, vagrant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MongoDB on Vagrant via Port Forwarding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947315/mongodb-on-vagrant-via-port-forwarding-issue)

when I try to connect to my vagrant server i'm getting the following error:

```
connecting to: localhost:4567/test
Mon Jan 23 17:17:34 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Mon Jan 23 17:17:34 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: DBClientBase::findN:     transport error: localhost:4567 query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } shell/mongo.js:86
exception: connect failed
```

I'm port forwarding 27017 to 4567 for Vagrant.

I'm new to mongo and have been hitting my head up against this for 4 days now.

Any thoughts?